MPI - One MPI_Send to multiple listeners
the thing is that I'm writting a programm in C using MPI. I the objective is to have N processes in the programme and once initiated one process send a token to a random different process, repeating this for 10 times. The first time is the rank 0 process the one that have to do it. This is an exercise and after expending several hours searching and trying different ways I try asking this here. I've tested, non blocking and MPI_Probe ... But the main thing is why if try this with more than one processor(part of code that I attach)  the program freezes, with two it runs ok.
    if (my_world_rank == 0)
    {
        MPI_Send(&token, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("Proceso %d envía token %d \n", my_world_rank, token);
    }else{

        
        MPI_Recv(&token, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("Proceso %d recibe token %d \n", my_world_rank, token);
    }

I tried to run the programme with more than 2 processors but it freezes and i expectec it to work.

what do you think happen on rank 2?

It will wait to receive a token from any source, doesn't it?

Yes, and who is sending that token?

so, every single process must get a token in order for the others to keep going on their program?

thanks Victor for the follow-up question :-)

For every MPI_Receive there must be an MPI_Send called. With 3 MPI ranks you call 1 Send and 2 Receives. That means one receive will wait forever since no Send is ever called.

You need one send for every receive.  Try this:
int np;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);

int tag = 42;

if (my_world_rank == 0)
{
    for (int target=1; target < np; target++) {
        MPI_Send(&token, 1, MPI_INT, target, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("Proceso %d envía token %d \n", my_world_rank, token);
    }
} else {
    MPI_Recv(&token, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Proceso %d recibe token %d \n", my_world_rank, token);
}

However, you are just doing the broadcast pattern and MPI_Bcast will be significantly faster.
